# Redux preloaded state is overwriting my application state

Tags: reactjs, redux

To create a session I am storing a JWToken in the localStorage (not the most secure place - I know). To allow the user to refresh the browser window I am persisting the user state in redux:

```
const getPersistedState = () => {
    try {
      const persistedToken = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('token'));
      const persistedTimeStamp = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authTimeStamp'));
      if (persistedToken === null ||
          persistedTimeStamp === null) {
        return undefined
      }
      const persistedState = { user: { auth: {
            token: persistedToken,
            authTimeStamp: persistedTimeStamp,
            authed: true,
          }
        }
      }
      return persistedState
    } catch(e) {
      return {}
    }
}

const persistedState = getPersistedState()
const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    persistedState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
)
```

My problem is that the whole user state gets overwritten by this if the store gets updated. So I can't define an `INITIAL_STATE` object on my user reducer, because it will get overwritten instantly.

**Is there a way to achieve persisted state that can merge with the existing state, that will give me the ability to define an `INITIAL_STATE`?**

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't mean you add the prefix persist means the reducer is the best place to handle it.

`localStorage` interaction is more of a component thing.

So try dispatching an action `SET_TOKEN` in the component after all token attributes are retrieved successfully via `localStorage`.

```
// Component.js
const getPersistedState = () => {
  try {
    // TODO: get all attributes in local storage
    this.props.setToken(...attributes); // dispatches SET_TOKEN action
  } catch(e) {
    // error
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.getPersistedState(); // retrieve token attributes
}

// Reducer.js
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  user: {
    auth: {
      token: '',
      authTimeStamp: -1,
      authed: false,
    }
  }
};

// User Reducer handles SET_TOKEN action
const user = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case Action.SET_TOKEN:
      const { token, authTimeStamp, authed } = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        auth: {
          token,
          authTimeStamp,
          auth,
        }
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hm, I see your point - though it does not really answer my question unfortunately. Your solution is definitely an option to solve the problem I am facing. The proposed solution comes with major carveats, however - e. g. serving current state to nested components. Sure this can be solved but I do think there are other more suitable options to solve this.